# OpenGL Textures vs. Array Buffer

Tags: c++, arrays, opengl, vbo, vao

I have a grid based terrain with integer x and y coordinates.
Im currently send an array with 6 float values per vertex. 3 for position and 3 for normal coordinates.
I wonder if its more efficient to simple store normal and height data in 2 separate textures and just sending an array with 2 uv coordines per vertex.
The problem might be that the textures must have very high resolution like 4096x4096 or bigger.

Comment: If you want to treat something extremely large like a texture, that's what texture buffer objects are for. You effectively get a 1D texture that can store a lot more data than any 2D texture ever could. But you have to use `texelFetch (...)`, so they're only vaguely similar to 2D textures; and basically made obsolete by SSBOs on newer hardware.

Comment: @Andon M. Coleman Is there a common texture size from which i should use texture buffers?

Comment: Technically, implementations are only required to support texture buffers with 65536 texels, but most support absolutely massive textures (my system can use texture buffers with an effective 2D resolution of 16384x16384). See [here](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec44.core.pdf#page=235) for more details.

Comment: i tried texture buffer with RGBA_32F format, 1024x1024 size and i got almost (~ 5fps less) the same performance as with the vertex array